# MTS ultra Wifi device not working in ubuntu 13.10 via usb

Tags: internet

I would like to use an MTS Wifi USB. I could able to create a network connection manually using the credentials internet@internet.mtsindia.in, #777, Password MTS, but i cannot access the internet.Also while creating the connection the mobile broadband device is not shown in the dropdown. I can access the internet only through wifi , the manual connection is not working in my PC. Am using ubuntu 13.10.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to a kernel issue. Please consider updating your kernel by typing:

**`sudo apt-get install linux-generic`**

Then reboot your PC.

Comment: I have updated the kernel , but not working yet !